# Unsupported URL Type "npm:": npm:vue-loader@^16.0.0-beta.3

Tags: vue.js, npm, vue-cli

I created a project with Vue CLI `vue create my-project` and got this error:

```
npm ERR! code EUNSUPPORTEDPROTOCOL
npm ERR! Unsupported URL Type "npm:": npm:vue-loader@^16.0.0-beta.3

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/n/.npm/_logs/2020-09-10T05_10_36_489Z-debug.log
```

Npm version: 6.14.8, node version: 10.15.2.
I've googled this error but their answers not work to me. I also reinstall npm, node, vue but nothing good happens. Thank you for all your answers.

Answer (score 13):

Turn out that I just need to update Node version to 14.x